# plot Lag effect, dlnm package in R

Tags: r, plot, error-handling, lag, glm

I examine temperature related mortality using dlnm package in R. I want to interpret lag effect at specific temperatures using this code: `#crossbasis matrix`

`cb<-crossbasis(data$Temperature,lag=21,argvar=list(fun="ns", knots=quantile(data$Temperature,c(10,75,90)/100,na.rm=T)), arglag=list(knots=logknots(21,3)))`

`#model model<-glm(mortality ~ cb + ns(Time,df=8*11) + (DayOfTheWeek), data, family=quasipoisson)`

`cen<-25.4 #centering value for predictions`

`#predictions pred<-crosspred(cb,model,by=0.1,cen=cen, cumul=TRUE)`

If I run summary of pred I get this:

**PREDICTIONS: values: 418 centered at: 25.4 range: -7.6 , 34.1 lag: 0 21 exponentiated: yes cumulative: yes**

**MODEL: parameters: 20**
**class: glm lm**
**link: log**

Then I try to plot:

`plot(pred, "slices", var=1.8, col=2, pch=19, ylab="RR", xlab="Lag (days)")`

But I get this error message:

**Error in lines.crosspred(pred, "slices", var = 1.8: 'var' must match values used for prediction.**

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Would you to mind share the code about plotting lag effect at specific temperatures? I am new to dlnm and I cannot find it in the internet... Thank you!

Comment: This is the code I provided here: `plot(pred, "slices", var="Temp", col=2, pch=19, ylab="RR", xlab="Lag (days)")` where Temp is the specific temperature you want to plot the lag effect

Answer (score 0):

I used "" var and worked:

```
plot(pred, "slices", var="1.8", col=2, pch=19, ylab="RR", xlab="Lag (days)")
```